# How to delete edges of all flat surfaces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, edges

Is there a faster way to delete edges of a flat surface than doing it manually ? I have a terrain with multiple lakes and don't need to have so many vertices and edges on the water.

[image: Two lakes]

Here is a part where I started to do it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Select a face in the flat area, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Select Coplanar*. (It has a threshold setting, if needed, in its <kbd>F9</kbd> panel)
- Adjust if necessary, and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*. (Which, as Kuboå has just reminded us, also has a threshold setting, by Normal :) )

[image]

Comment: I was just about to link to @Kuboå ' s perfectly good answer, and mysteriously, they deleted it?

Comment: Selecting all like I did would also get rid of some shallow-angled faces from the mountainside instead of just the flats. First selecting the faces by normals like you do would be better practice for OP's desired result so I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Kuboå    Okydoky .. I genuinely _did_ need  the 'Normal' threshold in the  limited dissolve pointing out, so that's incorporated.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't see @Kuboa's anwer but it is correct that I only want to simplify the mesh in the lake areas and keep even all other faces.

Comment: Just for reference: with the extra step of creating a vertex group after selecting the lake, you could also use a Decimate modifier, with Collapse decimation. This would also give the option to only remove some of the geometry.